# Including two management_forms in django template; only one is returned

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to have two inline_formsets included in my template, but for some reason the management_form data is only being returned for one of them.

models.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class Magazine(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

forms.py:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author

BookFormset = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields=('title',), can_delete=True)
MagazineFormset = inlineformset_factory(Author, Magazine, fields=('title',), can_delete=True)
```

views.py:

```
def add_author(request):
    form = AuthorForm()
    book_formset = BookFormset(instance=Author(), prefix='magazines')
    magazine_formset = MagazineFormset(instance=Author(), prefix='magazines')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            author = form.save()
            book_formset = BookFormset(request.POST, instance=author, prefix='books')
            magazine_formset = MagazineFormset(request.POST, instance=author, prefix='magazines')
            if book_formset.is_valid() and magazine_formset.is_valid():
                book_formset.save()
                magazine_formset.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    return render(request, "form.html", {'form': form, 'book_formset': book_formset, 
                            'magazine_formset': magazine_formset, 'action': "Create"})
```

and finally, form.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h4>{{ action }}</h4>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<h3>Books</h3>
{{ magazine_formset.management_form }}
{{ book_formset.management_form }}
{{ book_formset }}
<h3>Magazines</h3>
{{ magazine_formset }}
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

This seems like it should be fairly straightforward, but I still get

```
ValidationError at /add/
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

Here is the POST data to show that the book_formset.management_form is not getting passed:

POST

Variable    Value

magazines-INITIAL_FORMS u'0'

magazines-1-title   u'sksd'

name    u'sdf'

magazines-1-id  u''

magazines-2-title   u''

magazines-2-id  u''

magazines-MAX_NUM_FORMS u'1000'

magazines-0-author  u''

magazines-0-title   u'sdlkfs'

magazines-1-author  u''

magazines-0-id  u''

magazines-TOTAL_FORMS   u'3'

csrfmiddlewaretoken u'oJ82pScHeSMKzcE7E19xZEa75nrBKyro'

magazines-2-author  u''

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GET part of your view, you've given both formsets the prefix "magazines".

Comment: Oh, that's not even fair.